# What's the difference of `require 'rails'` and `require 'rails/all'`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, require

I know that generally when we require a gem, the gem's lib path will be added to $LOAD_PATH. But I didn't find a `lib` path in my rails gem. When I execute `require 'rails'` and `require 'rails/all'` in my console, they get different output.

Answer (score 2):

Actually `require 'rails'` will require this file "rails/railties/lib/rails.rb"

While `require 'rails/all'` will require this file "rails/railties/lib/rails/all.rb"

The key point is that `railties` is the core of Rails.
 So now everything will be clear.